# When scheduling a pod into a node, does k8s take into account 'requested' or 'limit' resources?

Tags: kubernetes

Does kubernetes check for node affinity (in term of resources like cpu, memory...) the memory set as 'request' in pod definition, or the 'limit' set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scheduler looks at `request` values: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-requests-are-scheduled